# Plumber employment

Tags: employment, construction-law, contractor, work-permit, montana

Is there any legal issue with a property management company employing a journeyman plumber to do plumbing jobs in house?

The management company only manages related party owned properties, specifically one spouse owns a management company which manages for properties owned by companies owned by one spouse or the other.

To play Devil's advocate, I'd argue that this makes the management company essentially a plumbing contractor, and as such it has to be owned by a master plumber in order to hire a journeyman. That said, we would not be offering plumbing services to the public.

On the other hand, I would argue that the journeyman is licensed to do the work he is doing as an independent contractor and it would be routine for a management company to hire an independent contractor and pass the bill along to the property owner, so the only real difference is paying as an employee vs paying as a contractor.

I'd appreciate any guidance to get me started, but I understand this is likely state specific. The state is Montana.

Comment: You might want to make your hypotheses more intelligible: "*only manages related party owned properties*" What is a *related party owned property*? "*one spouse owns a management company which manages for properties owned by companies owned by one spouse or the other.*" Why would the management company care about whether the customer is a company *owned by one spouse or the other*? Unless I'm misreading your post, it is irrelevant whether a plumber is hired for in-house work versus for a business of outsourcing.

Comment: Laws governing plumbers vary considerably from state to state.

Comment: "...we would not be offering plumbing services to the public." Are *you* starting this management company? If so, this site it not for specific legal or business advice.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, if the management company has a plumbing contractors licence

[new-south-wales](/questions/tagged/new-south-wales)

Plumbing is “specialist work” under the [Home Building Act](https://legislation.nsw.gov.au/view/html/inforce/current/act-1989-147#sec.12) and a person (including corporations) who perform such work for the public must hold a current contractor’s licence (s12). Despite the name of the Act, the restriction on specialist work apply to all types of construction.

Since the management company does not own the properties, they are doing work for the public notwithstanding that that “public” is limited to related corporations.